# Check parent/child relationship between 2 nodes in Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Assume you have 2 `SyntaxNode`s in Roslyn and you want to check whether they are in a parent/child relationship.

Instead of using walkers and implementing the logic yourself (there are many ways for it, also using the `Parent` property), does Roslyn provide a utility method for this? Something like:

```
bool IsChildParentOf(SyntaxNode node1, SyntaxNode node2);
```

#### Why I am asking

So, just to clarify, I am asking because there might be an optimized way in Roslyn to do this:

```
bool IsChildOf(SyntaxNode node, SyntaxNode parent) {
  for (var currentNode = node; currentNode != null; currentNode = currentNode.Parent)
    if (currentNode == parent) return true

  return false;
}
```

For example, in browsers you have internal dictionaries keeping references to elements. These references help fastening the search operations in the tree. So maybe Roslyn has this feature as well?

Comment: Every node has a reference to its parent so.. yeah. Just use that? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/bd0e1d83c76e524ae08119028d2ef544ee080d35/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Syntax/SyntaxNode.cs#L594

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Thanks for pointing me to that question. But my point here is if the API offer this functionality out of the box instead of having developers implement it...

Comment: You want to know if there is a method that does literally `if(node1.Parent == node2 || node2.Parent == node1)`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Listen, to accomplish this in the classic way you need to implement a cycle and yes, do a very trivial comparison. Fine. Now, when you build such a big API like Roslyn which is all about trees, you might want to facilitate these operations and maybe you might even run some sort of optimized logic in order to fasten operations like parent/child relationship check (very common). Who knows if the API keeps a dict of all nodes and enables a smarter tree search (it happens in browsers for example)? That is why I am asking, of course I know how to implement a parent check cycle

Comment: Then no, I'm not aware of such a method.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a method either. Furthermore, I doubt that it is possible to construct anything significantly more efficient than the implementation you provided, or it would have to be something based on `parent.Span.Contains(child.Span)`

Comment: Or faster: `parent.FullSpan.Contains(child.FullSpan)`, see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/bd0e1d83c76e524ae08119028d2ef544ee080d35/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Syntax/SyntaxNode.cs#L81